# Setting the initial output value for state space block in MATLAB

Tags: control, state-space

I've got the following control loop in Simulink:
[image]
What I'm trying to do is to set the initial value for the output to be 23, right now it starts from 0 and I can't find any explanation how that's done, these are my ABCD parameters which I got from my 2nd order Transfer Function:

[image]

I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: Have you set the initial conditions in the state-space block?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [onine help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html) part of the parameters to be set is an `Initial conditions` entry in the block, itself (as mentioned by [AVK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552832/setting-the-initial-output-value-for-state-space-block-in-matlab#comment1440704_552832) in the comments):

> Initial conditions — Initial state vector
> 0 (default) | scalar | vector
>
> Specify the initial state vector.
> Limitations
>
> The initial conditions of this block cannot be inf or NaN.
> Programmatic Use
> Block Parameter: X0
> Type: character vector, string
> Values: scalar | vector
> Default: '0'

Comment: That's for the X-axis apparently, I did set that to 23 and nothing changed

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243116-initial-condition-in-state-space-block-in-simulink)? [Content edited by moderator]

Comment: I did not understand the answer in that link. The only reason I'm using the state space block is because the regular Transfer Function blocks wouldn't allow me to set initial values and I really don't know anything about state space hence why I didn't understand the answer in that link... [Content edited by moderator]

Comment: You can only set initial conditions to the states, because the states represent an accumulated version of the past. If you just want your output to start from a certain value, add a constant. If you want to start from a certain value of the *system's response*, you need to calculate the whole response, determine the states at that particular time, and then use them. For example if you want to avoid the transient and start in steady-state, the vector would be `[9,4592]`. For 32 V initial output set it to `[0,32/.000196]` (if I was out of place, that was not my intent).

Comment: I had a typo, the numbers weren't matching. The initial conditions for steady-state output are `[196u/42m, 0.9/196u]`.